# How to align header and body of a table when using JQuery tableScroll?

Tags: jquery, css

I made my tables scroll-able using JQuery tableScroll plugin. But it messes up the alignment of header and body. I read a lot about this issue in the web and I have tried a lot of css scenarios, but I still struggling with this problem. My js code is as follow:

> ```
> function makingTablesScrollable(table){
>    var scrollableTable = table;
>    var tableLength = scrollableTable.find('tbody tr').length;
>    var tableWidth = scrollableTable.width() - 18;
>    if(tableLength > 5) {
>     scrollableTable.tableScroll({
>         height:250,
>         width: tableWidth,
>         flush:true
>     });
>    }
>  }
> ```

and the css part is as below:

> ```
> table{
>       border-spacing: 0;
>       width: 590px;
>       display: table;
>       th, td{
>         max-width:170px;
>         min-width:65px;
>         max-height: 100px;
>   }
> }
> ```

Can anybody tell me what I need to add to my code to fix this issue? I am really thankful in advance.

Comment: can you make fiddle ?

Comment: yes.. Fiddle is more helpful.

Comment: here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qba06zd4/2/